# Upgraded MySql from 5.0 to 5.6 and joomla site will not load

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.0

I upgraded MySql from 5.0 to 5.6 and joomla site will not load. Any ideas on if there is something i need to change or how i get it back to 5.0?
Thanks!

Comment: Check your error logs, then upgrade your Joomla install if it can't work with a version of MySQL that's nearly a **decade** old.

Comment: i am surprised it is that old! i am working with host provider to try and resolve this issue as I am not too familiar with all pf this. probably why i broke the site. lol.

Comment: I have tried a new install of joomla and it won’t load either. Host is trying to roll it back to 5.0 the said but from what I was reading shouldn’t joomla work with MySQL 5.6? Then I think it has php 7. But need to double check.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Once there, the community will help you with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Had them downgrade mysql back to the version they run and the site works.